# Remote server randomly unreachable by single local machine

Tags: networking, ssh, ping

I have a number of machines in my home LAN: "A", "B", "C". I ssh to a remote server "X" from all of these, but most frequently from "A". (Seemingly) randomly, the connections from A to X become almost entirely blocked: ssh connections freeze, opening a new one is virtually impossible, and I can hardly ping X from A. However other machines in the same home LAN, ie B and C, can happily ping the IP of X and ssh to it.

It also happened that after ssh'ing from B to X for a while, X became unreachable to B, whilst A could ping and ssh X.

After a random while, anything from 1 hour to half a day, the problem sorts itself out.

I have no idea why this is happening, and any clues would be very much appreciated!

A pinging attempt the IP address of X from A :

```
me@A:~$ ping ip-address-of-X
PING ip-address-of-X (ip-address-of-X) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ip-address-of-X: icmp_seq=20 ttl=53 time=22.4 ms
^C
--- ip-address-of-X ping statistics ---
139 packets transmitted, 1 received, 99.2806% packet loss, time 417ms
```

Comment: Does machine X _receive_ the ping requests? Does it attempt to send replies? Are those replies being sent to the correct MAC address?

Comment: I am not an admin on X, so probably I can't check if X receives the ping requests. It's a university server and the admins were pretty sure that X had no issues when I raised the issue with them.

I don't know how to check which MAC address the replies are being sent to. I guess that's something that my router should do. I'll try to go through its logs.

Comment: Ah, right, so X is remote? If you're accessing a university server from home, then it definitely cannot distinguish your LAN machines from each other, not over IPv4 at least. The problem is somewhere else then.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought too. I don't know what setting in the router / clients would cause such a problem though.